# ActiveRecord linked entity not being saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an User that has a company, as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in my seeds.rb, I'm setting them up like this

```
cc = Company.find_by_name("SocialSky, Inc.") || Company.create(
  name: "Whatever Inc.",
  main_email: "person@example.com"
)

client = User.find_by_email('johndoe@gmail.com') || User.create( 
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
  company: cc
)
```

Later on, on a service, I'm doing

```
user_company = User.find_by_email('johndoe@gmail.com').company
```

And it's returning nil

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 3, you have to add company_id to attr_accessible.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one  :company
   attr_accessible : email
end
```

Then in seeds file, you should first do to verify if company is created or not.

```
 cc = Company.find_by_name("SocialSky, Inc.") || Company.create(
   name: "Whatever Inc.",
   main_email: "person@example.com")

 p cc
```

and later

```
 client = User.find_by_email('johndoe@gmail.com')
 if client.blank?
   u = User.new(email: 'johndoe@gmail.com')
   u.company_id = cc.id
   u.save
 end
```

Comment: One more thing please add name and main_email as attr_accessible to company as well

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `first_or_create`?

```
cc = Company.where(name: "SocialSky, Inc.").first_or_create |company|
  company.name =  "Whatever Inc."
  compnay.main_email =  "person@example.com"
)

client = User.where(email: 'johndoe@gmail.com').first_or_create |user|
  user.email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
  user.company: cc
)
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create